# Choose which distinct value to take based on another column - PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, distinct, partition

I have a table of this kind:

| name | tag |
| --- | --- |
| inter | cep |
| inter | a |
| inter | b |
| milan | a |
| milan | c |
| juve | r |
| juve | cep |
| naples | h |
| naples | p |

And I need to take **only the distinct names**, in a way that if the tag = cep take that one, otherwise **take a random one** (maybe the first one, but not important)

so the output should be something like:

| name | tag |
| --- | --- |
| inter | cep |
| milan | a |
| juve | cep |
| naples | h |

I tried different ways using row_number() like:

```
select name, tag
from (
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as row_number
   from table
   ) as rows
where tag='cep' or row_number = 1
```

but this doesn't eliminate some of the name duplicates, especially those where "cep" is present but is not the first one in the partition (like name = juve for instance)

SOLUTION?

Answer (score 2):

Use a case expression in the partition order by to get cep rows first:

```
select name, tag
from (
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by name 
                             order by case when tag = 'cep' then 0 else 1 end) as row_number
   from table
   ) as rows
where row_number = 1
```

Demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/6r-JDu90

Comment: Great, thanks! That's what I was missing.